# Migrating hashing data to another algorithm

Tags: database, hash, migration

Several years ago, everyone was hashing their passwords to the database using MD5. Now the new thing is bcrypt. And tomorrow there will be something else.

My question is: Suppose the bcrypt algorithm has been defeated, but one has filled his database with this bcrypt hashing technique. How can we migrate all those hashes when the next newer-and-genius algorithm is released?

Does the solution is to wait for the customers to login to the site and then update the database using this next gen technique? It doesn't seems very secure, while supposing the actual algorithm used has been defeated.

Comment: The only other option is to block their accounts and request authentication using other factors (like email).

Comment: You could just block the logins if they haven't logged in from the date you switched to the new hash, ask them to verify via email then subsequently update their details using whatever new hash?